# how random quiz image with array android?

Tags: java, android

Hay master i want to ask to make a random quiz with array of images how yes, i've tried but can not random the whole matter.

This is his coding if anything is wrong `enter code here`

```
  Random r = new Random();
  `enter code here`int n= r.nextInt(9);
  private int [] pertanyaan={R.drawable.hidung, R.drawable.rambut,     
          R.drawable.leher, R.drawable.pundak, R.drawable.telinga, R.drawable.pergelangan_kaki, R.drawable.tangan,
          R.drawable.wajah, R.drawable.lengan, R.drawable.pundak};


  public String [] pilihanganda={
          "Perhatikan gambar tersebut gambar diatas?",
          "Perhatikan gambar tersebut diatas?",
          "Apakah yang Harus diucapkan Pada Temanmu yang Sedang Galau?",
          "asdasdasldkasldkasldkasdas",
          "dfwwqdadafasdasd",
          "Perhatikan gambar tersebut diatas?",
          "Perhatikan gambar tersebut diatas?",
          "Perhatikan gambar tersebut diatas?",
          "Perhatikan gambar tersebut diatas?",
          "Perhatikan gambar tersebut diatas?",

          };

 private int [] pilihan_a={R.drawable.wajah, R.drawable.hidung, R.drawable.rambut, R.drawable.pergelangan_kaki, 
                    R.drawable.tangan, R.drawable.rambut, R.drawable.leher, R.drawable.lengan, R.drawable.pundak
                    , R.drawable.pundak};
 private int [] pilihan_b={R.drawable.hidung, R.drawable.wajah,R.drawable.pundak, R.drawable.tangan, 
                    R.drawable.pergelangan_kaki, R.drawable.leher, R.drawable.rambut, R.drawable.lengan, R.drawable.telinga
                    , R.drawable.pundak};
 private  int [] pilihan_c={R.drawable.pundak, R.drawable.lengan, R.drawable.tangan, R.drawable.hidung, R.drawable.pergelangan_kaki
                    , R.drawable.telinga, R.drawable.pergelangan_kaki, R.drawable.wajah, R.drawable.leher,
                    R.drawable.rambut};
 private  int [] pilihan_d={R.drawable.pergelangan_kaki, R.drawable.tangan, R.drawable.hidung, R.drawable.pundak, 
          R.drawable.rambut, R.drawable.pundak, R.drawable.lengan, R.drawable.leher, R.drawable.telinga, R.drawable.pergelangan_kaki};

  public static String [] jawaban ={"B","C","C","A","D","B","D","D","D","B"};


   @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.quiz_2);


          soal = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
          soalnya = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Soal);
          soal.setImageResource(pertanyaan[n]);
          soalnya.setText(pilihanganda[n]);
          imgB=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.pilihan2);
          imgC=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.pilihan3);
          imgD=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.pilihan4);
          imgA=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.pilihan1);




          imgA.setImageResource(pilihan_a[n]);
          imgA.setOnClickListener(this);
          imgB.setImageResource(pilihan_b[n]);
          imgB.setOnClickListener(this);
          imgC.setImageResource(pilihan_c[n]);
          imgC.setOnClickListener(this);
          imgD.setImageResource(pilihan_d[n]);
          imgD.setOnClickListener(this);

          nomor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.No);
          nomor.setText("Soal " + no++);

          salahbenar =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.salahbenar);
          salahbenar.setText("");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to generate random number between 0 to n. Set generated index image on ImageView:

```
Random r = new Random();
int i1 = r.nextInt(n- 0) + 0;
```

It will include 0 and exclude n.

Comment: Thank you, sorry i've tried but random only 1 problem, maybe there is another solution